# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Sending notifications between Android devices

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are creating a task manager application. We want to add the possibility to add multiple contributors to a task. Thus when a user adds people (that have the application), they will receive a notification informing them.

We are already using Firebase for a lot of our app's features. So I wanted to use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to implement the notification part. But I noticed that we must have a server (that we don't have) to use this feature. We only want to have the user (adding people to the task) to send a request to FCM and after FCM will send the notification to each concerned user.

My question is: Is there a possibility to implement this part without server?

Thank you for your precious help :)

Comment: I've used FCM in my apps, as far as I know the answer is NO

Comment: @KH_AJU do you know if there is any other solution to implement the feature?

Comment: If you don't want to run your own server, there are 3rd party services which help you sending Push Notifications to devices. One was Parse by Facebook which closed down. However you can google for Parse alternatives. However you might need to look into how to make it a user initiated thing. Anyways your quests would need to go through that 3rd party service AFAIK.